# Excel Formula - Rank

Tags: excel, formula, rank

I am trying to figure out how to rank values based on the percentages.  Which ever cell has the highest percentage, should be ranked 1st.
Then who ever has the 2nd highest percentage, should be ranked 2nd.  Then same thing for 3rd value.

However, I am comparing 12 different values (using cells A1 to A12).  How do I rank each value but ONLY show the first 3 highest percentages?
I have been using the RANK value, however, I don't want all 12 values to be shown..so values from 4-12 should not display or should be hidden.

Also, I need it to be accurate within 0.1.
For example, if one value is 18.5% and another is 18.7%, I need the 18.7% to be ranked higher, and not equal (which is what happens with the RANK formula).

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: I would use the filter / table built in wizard, you can then apply filter condition to the column.. e.g. bigger than, between, etc. Which is more flexible and easy to change than a formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in **A1** through **A12**, in **C1** enter:

```
=LARGE($A$1:$A$12,ROW())
```

and copy down through **C4**

[image]

To show fewer items, copy through **C3**, etc.

**EDIT#1:**

Leave the formulas in column **C**.  In column **D** just enter 1, 2, 3.
Then in **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$D$3,2,FALSE),"")
```

and copy down.  Here is an example:

[image]

**EDIT#2:**

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$12,0)<4,RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$12,0),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: I understand, however, I forgot to mention that the way the spreadsheet is set up is that the rankings (1, 2, and 3) have to show up below its appropriate cell, on row B.  For example, if A4 has the highest percentage (therefore, ranked 1st), a 1 should be display on B4, etc...for the top 3 values (anything below 3 should show nothing but a blank cell)

Comment: @ArsenedeConde  I understand and will update the post!

Comment: Thank you! it works.  Anyway to have all of this combined into one formula so only 1 column is used, for example, column B?

Comment: @ArsenedeConde ................Perhaps with a **Rank()** formula............I'll give it some thought...............